# error: passing argument 1 of 'contar_elementos' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: array, funciones

Tengo un programa que pretende calcular la cantidad de elementos que tiene un arreglo.
Para eso el arreglo entra a una función contar_elementos que cuenta la cantidad de elementos y devuelve el total. El tema es que cuando intento mostar el contenido del arreglo tira el siguiente error:

```
 error: passing argument 1 of 'contar_elementos' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

¿Cómo se puede solventar la falla o error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAMANIO 12

int contar_elementos(int a[TAMANIO]);

int main()
{
    int a[ TAMANIO ] = { 1, 3, 5, 4, 7, 2, 99, 16, 45, 67, 89, 45};
    printf( "El total de los elementos del arreglo es %d\n", contar_elementos(a[TAMANIO]));
    return 0;
}

int contar_elementos(int a[TAMANIO]){
    int i, total = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < TAMANIO; i++ ) {
        total = total + 1;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que esto te puede ayudar un poco, quizás es un poco más largo el código pero te da la solución. Espero haberte ayudado.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int contar_elementos[100];

int main()
{
///Array con elementos.
int contar_elementos[] = { 1, 3, 5, 4, 7, 2, 99, 16, 45, 67, 89, 45};

int tamanio_del_tipo_de_dato; ///Ej. Tamaño de un Int (4 bytes), de un Char (1 byte)
int tamanio_del_array; ///Aplica sizeof al array
int cantidad_elementos;

///Obtenemos el tamano de un int y del array usando sizeof.
tamanio_del_array = sizeof(contar_elementos);
tamanio_del_tipo_de_dato = sizeof(int);

///Para calcular la cantidad de elementos
///Dividimos el tamaño del array, entre el tamaño de su tipo de dato, por ejemplo enteros.
cantidad_elementos = tamanio_del_array / tamanio_del_tipo_de_dato;

cout << endl;
cout << "Cantidad de elementos: " << cantidad_elementos << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Si, pero no es como yo lo quería. 1ero El programa está en C, no en C++. 2do. Quiero calcular la cantidad de elementos en una función y no dentro del propio cuerpo del programa.

Comment: Esta es la única respuesta válida.

Answer (score 0):

Dos cosas:
1 Hay que desreferenciar el arreglo, con un &
2 Hay que parar la consola
Programa completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define TAMANIO 12

int contar_elementos(int a[]);

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 3, 5, 4, 7, 2, 99, 16, 45, 67, 89, 45};
    printf( "El total de los elementos del arreglo es %d\n", contar_elementos(&a[TAMANIO]));
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int contar_elementos(int a[]){
    int i, total = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < TAMANIO; i++ ) {
        total = total + 1;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor es usar punteros que son las direcciones donde empiezan los arreglos, quedaría así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAMANIO 12

int contar_elementos(int*);

int main()
{
    int a[ TAMANIO ] = { 1, 3, 5, 4, 7, 2, 99, 16, 45, 67, 89, 45};
    int n = (int)contar_elementos(a);
    printf( "El total de los elementos del arreglo es %d\n",n );
    return 0;
}

int contar_elementos(int* a){
    int i, total = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < TAMANIO; i++ ) {
        total = total + 1;
    }
    return total;
}
```

También se puede colocar un número negativo en la lista que indicaría el final de los valores válidos y mediante una comparación en el for, se retornaría el número de elementos hasta allí usando break para salir del bucle o directamente un return.